# Terminate a threads of multipage tkinter application?

Tags: python, multithreading, tkinter, python-multiprocessing, servo

I have made **Tkinter application** which contains two pages.
Each page has **threads**, which read the status continuously from *servo machine*.

The problem is when I try to switch to another page. It shows errors due to the thread.

Can you help me, I can **kill the thread**.
or
suggest me another way to solve my problem.

```
def wind():
    global appThread
    appThread=False
    tp1.join()
    frame1.destroy()
    frame2.destroy()
    frame3.destroy()
    frame4.destroy()
    frame5.destroy()
    frame6.destroy()
    frame7.destroy()
    frame8.destroy()
    app2 = importlib.import_module("app2")
    # app2.app2.onoff(self,app2thread)
    app2.app2.ap2func(self)

def upread():
    print("upread in app",appThread)
    print("tp1 alive", tp1.is_alive())
    while True:
        if appThread==True:
            if master.config_init() > 0:
                # pavr = ctypes.c_uint32.from_buffer_copy(master.slaves[0].sdo_read(index=pav, subindex=parasub)).value
                # # print(pavr)
                # pavr = str(pavr)
                # opmr = ctypes.c_uint8.from_buffer_copy(master.slaves[0].sdo_read(index=opm, subindex=parasub)).value
                # opmr = str(opmr)
                for device in master.slaves:
                    pavr = ctypes.c_uint32.from_buffer_copy(device.sdo_read(index=pav, subindex=parasub)).value
                    pavr = str(pavr)
                    opmr = ctypes.c_uint8.from_buffer_copy(device.sdo_read(index=opm, subindex=parasub)).value
                    opmr = str(opmr)
            if opmr == "3":
                jbtn.configure(relief="sunken", bg="#3366ff")
                abtn.configure(relief="raised", bg="blue")
            elif opmr == "1":
                abtn.configure(relief="sunken", bg="#3366ff")
                jbtn.configure(relief="raised", bg="blue")
            else:
                jbtn.configure(relief="raised", bg="blue")
                abtn.configure(relief="raised", bg="blue")
            pavvalue.set(pavr)
            time.sleep(0.1)
            print("app:", appThread)
            pass
        else:
            break
    pass
    
tp1 = threading.Thread(target=upread)
# set daemon: polling thread will exit if main thread exit
tp1.daemon = True
tp1.start()
```

Comment: Without knowing exactly how you set up the thread it is impossible for anyone else to reproduce the problem you are facing. Please edit the question to include a [minimal complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  Also please refer to [this guide on how to ask a question that may be answered](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Do a preliminary debugging and post a [mre] and debugging details. Anyway, why not set ```appThread``` to False and join the thread?

Comment: @relent95 because it will be multipage application. user can re-visit the page ,i think join() method can led to accumulation of threads ??

Comment: Please edit for the [mre] guide at first. I can't understand your comment without that.